# Can handle all error into only module in vba?

Tags: vba, error-handling

Can i handle all error in VBA Project?

> Class Module: **ErrorHandle**
> 'Class Error Handle

```
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        'If Any error occurs in VBA Project
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'Do something
        End If
    End Sub
```

> In Module

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim a as Integer
    'When error, auto go to class Error Handle instead of handle each error?
    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox (5/0)
End Sub
```

> I have searched in internet but not found solution

Can i handle all error in VBA Project?

> Class Module: **ErrorHandle**
> 'Class Error Handle

```
 Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        'If Any error occurs in VBA Project
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'Do something
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbYesOnly
        End If
    End Sub
```

> In Module

```
Public Sub Test()
        Dim a as Integer
        'When error, auto goto class Error Handle?
        MsgBox (5/0)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to have centralised error handling - I haven't worked out how to include it in a class, but I have a dedicated module in my projects.
Rather than going through all the detail (I'm not sure I can share my code anyway as it is copyrighted) have a look at this article [on VBA Error Handling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/) I adapted my model from the ideas there - if you already know and understand the VBA Err object then jump straight to "A Simple Error Handling Strategy"

Comment: Thank you very much so reply, This your link is raise error all sub-module and handle it in parent module.

Comment: This is a solution but not best practice

Comment: @HoangLongUOB What would you consider best practice given the constraints of VBA?

Comment: Sorry, but your solution almost all developers can think so.

Comment: I don't know VBA can working that, but you say it is posible then your solution is not best practice. Sorry my bad english.

Comment: To be clear - you asked "Can i handle all error in VBA project?" I provided you with a solution. 
I may have misled you with the "I have a dedicated module in my projects" - that module is to handle my application level errors. I have similar set ups within my Class modules, and forms modules. The model I have adapted allows me to log and report errors at the appropriate level with a fuller stack history than is nomally common in VBA programs - normally considered "best practice"

Comment: Thank you very much @CHill60, But it's not a solution I expected.